# BizTalk BAM Browser - Column Chooser - works on Win 7 but not BizTalk Server (Win 2012/R2)

Tags: biztalk, portal, biztalk-2016, biztalk-bam

My laptop is Windows 7 with IE 11.0.9600.18665 and when I access the BAM portal everything works fine.

BizTalk 2016 is installed on Win 2012/R2, with IE 11.0.9600.18666.  But on the Win 2012 server, when I click "Activity Search", select an activity, and then use the "Column Chooser" and click the ">>" button to move the field from the left to the right, nothing happens.

I'm logged on with the same credentials on each. Why would have this issue on the server?

Comment: Press F12 and see what version of IE it is emulating working vs non-working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your localhost to compatibility view of internet explorer.

For more info:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_mode

How to change it:

[image]

Localhost (current site) will show in top box, then click "Add" and it moves to lower box: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly!   I added a reference and a couple of screen shots.